# Controller and workers - signal to start/stop

Tags: c, synchronization

I have multiple workers forked from parent process and need to inform them all at exactly the same time to run / stop;

Parent:

```
while(1)
{    
    workers_start!
    usleep(work_time);
    workers_stop!
    usleep(sleep_time);
}
```

What should I use to inform them ALL quick(!)? Semaphores (counting N), mutexes, signals (after execve forked program)? I heard that semaphores/mutexes are slow. I'm not sure about signals but I don't know if sending so many signals is a good idea (N workers * 1 or 2 signals / per 0.2sec, where N is cpu cores).

Sorry, it's about linux.

Comment: Experiment with all options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to assign all your worker processed to a process group. You can do this by calling

```
setpgid(pid_t pid, pid_t pgid)
```

Where "pid is the the return of the "fork()" call for each of your workers, and pgid is the project group ID of all your workers, and should be the same for all workers. The manual page is here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpgrp.2.html

Then you can send a signal to all your processes with one single call to

```
killpg(int pgrp, int sig)
```

Where pgrp is the group that you assigned to all your workers in the step above. As for the values of "sig" in the call of killpg, if you have a POSIX platform, you might want to user the user defined siganls, for instance SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 for signalling start and stop respectively. If not, you can use standard signals and capture them (override their behaviour). The manual page to killpg is here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html

I hope this is clear enough and is similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about it. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Operating system you're using. Generally information of the quality "I heard semaphores are slow" are always to be taken with a grain of salt. Some quick testing will probably reveal the best solution for your case :)